# How to fix "Gdk-WARNING : XSetErrorHandler() .... In JavaFX application while generating report using Jasper Report?

Tags: java, javafx, jasper-reports, jodatime

How to fix
`"(java:2606): Gdk-WARNING **: XSetErrorHandler() called with a GDK error trap pushed Don't do that"`

I'm using `Jasper Report 6.12.x`

> `JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);`
>
> **`JasperViewer` extends `JFrame` and that cause of warning above.**

How to fix it or should I ignore it?

Comment: Duplicates: [How to fix “(java:22494): Gdk-WARNING…”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55446534/876298)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "(java:22494): Gdk-WARNING..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55446534/how-to-fix-java22494-gdk-warning)